# Difference in len() and .nunique with relation to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have defined a Pandas dataframe which contains a column name as 'emp_title'. I want to see the total number of unique entries in that specific column.

I used:

```
len(df['emp_title'].unique())
```

which gives me a value of 173106

whereas when I use:

```
df['emp_title'].nunique()
```

it gives me a value of 173105 which should be the actual size.

Can any one explain why I shouldn't be using the code with the len() function. Or is there probably an issue with the dataset at play here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means there is some missing value(s), because [`Series.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html) by default remove missing values.

So for same output change default parameter `dropna=True` to `False`:

```
df['emp_title'].nunique(dropna=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `len` the length of all elements in a list / array, and `unique()` returns of all unique elements **including** missing ones `nan`, whereas `nunique()` doesn't take into accoung `nan`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,np.nan]})
print(df['A'].nunique()
```

Rightfully returns 4, and

```
print(df['A'].unique())
```

Returns the list of all unique elements:

```
[ 1.  2.  3.  4. nan]
```

Which has a length of 5.